# How to load an entity from a service in a *ngFor

Tags: java, angular

So let's say for example I want to list a set of students in Angular2 I am pulling the data from a java backend with a service, and the fields are:

- id
- name
- age
- field
- universityId

Now when I display this on my webpage, I do not wish to display the universityId but the university name. I should mention there is a university entity:

- id
- name
- city

How can I display the name of the university instead of its Id in my webpage, without creating a new field in the student entity? I know how to do this with one student, but how can I do this on an *ngFor loop?

Thank you so much for your help, I hope my question is clear.

For example:

```
//student.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StudentService } from 'my/studentService/path';
import {Student} from 'my/studentModel/path';
import { UniversityService } from 'my/universityService/path';
 import { University } from 'my/univeristyModel/path';
@Component({
selector: 'student',
templateUrl: './student.component.html'
})
export class StudentComponent implements OnInit {
students = Student [];
university: University;

constructor(
private studentService : StudentService;
private universityService : UniversityService;
){}

loadAll(){
this.studentService.query(myParameters).subscribe(students =>
this.students = students; 
}

ngOnInit(){
this.loadAll();
}

}
```

And in my HTML

```
//student.component.html

<table>
<tr *ngFor="let student of students">
                <td><a [routerLink]="['../student', student.id ]">{{student.id}}</a></td>
                <td>{{student.name}}</td>
                <td>{{student.age}}</td>
                <td>{{student.field}}</td>
                <td>{{student.universityID}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I do have a universityService, and I can retrieve a university with a universityId. How do I do this so that I can display the university name and not its id in my HTML?

I tried this solution, but I get a never ending loop in my GET method:

```
//student.component.ts
 public loadUniversityName(id){
        this.universityService.find(id).subscribe(university => {
            this.university = university;
            return this.university.name;
        });
    }
```

And I inserted this in my HTML:

```
//student.component.html

<td>{{loadUniversityName(student.univeristyId)}}</td>
```

Comment: Can you add your html code?

Comment: This kind of aggregation have to be in your component, not your view. Just pass an object with the good properties to your view, handle the rest in backend.

Comment: @echonax Just added it

Comment: @Sakuto Can I call my universityService in my component.ts to then add it to my student array?

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting list of students from the server, you need to have the entire object UniversityEntity inside StudentObject instead of universityId.
In case of ngFor, you should have code like this:

```
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let student of students">
   <td><a [routerLink]="['../student', student.id ]"> {{student.universityEntity.id}}</a></td>
   <td>{{student.name}}</td>
   <td>{{student.age}}</td>
   <td>{{student.field}}</td>
   <td>{{student.universityEntity.name}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So your object should look like this:

```
students: any[] = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Mark',
    age: 22,
    field: 'Science',
    universityEntity: {
       id: 1,
       name: 'Cambridge',
       city: 'Cambridge'
    }
}]
```

Comment: This is a solution indeed, but I would rather do this in front and not touch my backend. I know it will be two REST calls, but it seems more efficient. If I modify everything in my backend and eager load everything, my performance will go down! So I'm looking for a solution in the front end! Thanks for your answer though :)

Comment: Well, you can get the list of all locations and loop through all studens and match universityId with id from location list and  in the frontend join name of university to student object.

Comment: @AndreDebuisne so do two rest calls? I don't understand what's the problem here. Of course you can't display the universityName if you don't have it : /

Comment: @echonax I did, but it doesn't work! Can't seem to do the rest call in my view. I edited my post to show you guys

Comment: You need to return value to the method loadUniversityName()   
`return this.universityService.find(id).subscribe(university => {`